# Setting cookies within an iFrame

Tags: javascript, html, cookies, iframe, dns

I know this is a very talked about subject but just wanted to check something with you knowledgeable people.

I've got a domain, say domain-A, that is out of my control, housing an application from domain-B, developed by me, in an iFrame. The application within the iFrame uses cookies a lot. Should this work?

I'm not trying to read cookies between domain-A and domain-B, I purely want to set cookies in domain-B and read them in domain-B.

All seems fine in Chrome but IE doesn't want to play the game.

Can anybody give me some guidance please?

Thanks,

Andy.

Comment: Don't worry. Sorted it. Added a P3P header to IIS and it sorted it :)

Answer (score 2):

From the server point of view, this should work fine. Your domain B will receive cookies from the IFRAME, as if it were just another web-page.

From the client side: sending the cookie could depend on policies set by the browser, of even by the user. Fiddle with the security level of your domain and the cookie settings in IE to get a hint of what is going on.